# Solve $y''+xy'-2y=e^x$ for $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y''+xy'-2y=e^x$ for $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

I'm trying the following reasoning:

Let $$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n.$$
Then $$y'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1} \quad \textrm{and} \quad y''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^n.$$

Then, expading $e^x$ we get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+(n-2)a_n)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Therefore, $$a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+(n-2)a_n=\frac{1}{n!}\Rightarrow a_{n+2}=\frac{1-n!(n-2)a_n}{(n+2)!}.$$

From $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ we get that $a_0=a_1=0$.

Thus $a_2=\frac{1}{4!}$, $a_3=\frac{1}{5!}$, $a_4=-\frac{1}{6!}$, $a_5=-\frac{2}{7!}$, $a_6=\frac{5}{8!}\cdots$

I cannot get an explicit formula to $a_n$.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $$\left\{-\left(x^2+1\right) \int_1^0 2 \sqrt{2} e^{K[1]}
   H_{-3}\left(\frac{K[1]}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \, dK[1]+\left(x^2+1\right) \int_1^x 2
   \sqrt{2} e^{K[1]} H_{-3}\left(\frac{K[1]}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \, dK[1]+2
   e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} x (x+2)} \left(-2
   F\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sqrt{2} (x-1)\right)+2
   F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sqrt{2}\right)
   H_{-3}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right\}$$ using the Hermite and Dawson functions.  So I wouldn't try this by hand.

Comment: What about if I change to $y''+xy'-2y=e$? That is the question, but I thought it was a typo.

Comment: Oh jeeeezzz... then the solution is $y(x) = \frac{e x^2}{2}$.  Please don't waste our time with typos!!!!

Comment: But when have you seen $\mathcal L(y)=e$ before? I really doubt it.